# R - date sequence with condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
test <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(4, 6, 9, 12),
    open = c(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01")),
    closed = c(as.Date("2011-12-01"), as.Date("2011-12-31"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"))
  )
```

My goal is to get each date that overlapped or reached last day in year. Since id 4 was started at 2011 and ended before last day, there should be NA for it. id 6 reached last day in 2011 but not in 2012, same for id 9.

Result should be

```
summary <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(4, 6, 9, 12),
    open = c(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01")),
    closed = c(as.Date("2011-12-01"), as.Date("2011-12-31"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31")),
    open_summary = c(NA, 2011, 2011, 2011),
    closed_summary = c(NA, 2011, 2011, 2015)
  )
```

Then I'd like to create a sequence from these dates so result should be

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    y = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015),
    id  = c(6, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
#create a lookup table of year end dates
yrend <- data.table(YR_END=seq(as.Date("2010-12-31"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="1 year"))[,
    YR := year(YR_END)]

setDT(test)
#create open_summary column since its just the end of the year of the open column
test[, open_summary := year(open)]
#lookup the year for the closed date
test[, closed_summary := yrend[test, on=.(YR_END>=open, YR_END<=closed), mult="last", YR]]

#create the sequence in part 2 of the qn
test[!is.na(open_summary) & !is.na(closed_summary), 
    .(y=open_summary:closed_summary), id]
```

`test` output:

```
   id       open     closed open_summary closed_summary
1:  4 2011-01-01 2011-12-01         2011             NA
2:  6 2011-01-01 2011-12-31         2011           2011
3:  9 2011-01-01 2012-01-01         2011           2011
4: 12 2011-01-01 2015-12-31         2011           2015
```

the other output:

```
   id    y
1:  6 2011
2:  9 2011
3: 12 2011
4: 12 2012
5: 12 2013
6: 12 2014
7: 12 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution, also using `lubridate` (for the `year` function)...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

summary <- test %>% 
  mutate(open_summary = year(open) * (year(open) > year(open - 1)),
         closed_summary = (year(closed + 1) - 1) * (year(closed + 1) > year(open)))

output <- summary %>% 
  filter(open_summary * closed_summary > 1) %>% 
  mutate(open_year = map2(open_summary, closed_summary, seq)) %>% 
  select(id, open_year) %>% 
  unnest(c(open_year))

summary
  id       open     closed open_summary closed_summary
1  4 2011-01-01 2011-12-01         2011              0
2  6 2011-01-01 2011-12-31         2011           2011
3  9 2011-01-01 2012-01-01         2011           2011
4 12 2011-01-01 2015-12-31         2011           2015

output
     id open_year
1     6      2011
2     9      2011
3    12      2011
4    12      2012
5    12      2013
6    12      2014
7    12      2015
```

If either `open_summary` or `closed_summary` is zero, that is equivalent to your `NA` row.